# How to get a Value For FormField with suffix value

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using angular material formfield with suffix dropdowns with units like cm,mm,etc..,In that I need a value of given number as input and suffix selected dropdowns value in one formcontrolName ,Here its my code.

```
<mat-form-field class="flex ">
    <mat-label>Width</mat-label>
        <input matInput [formControlName]="'width'" type="number" autocomplete="off">
        <mat-select matSuffix >
           <ng-container *ngFor="let unit of unitArray" >
               <mat-option [value]="unit" >{{unit}}</mat-option>
           </ng-container>
         </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>


unitArray = ['pt','cm','mm','in','pi']
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to combine both inputs in a single formControl. The reason is that the binding needs one single source of truth, e.g. for validation. You can just define a separate `FormControl` for your `unit` selection like:

```
form = new FormGroup({
  width: new FormControl(),
  unit: new FormControl()
});
```

and then bind your select to the new formControl:

```
<mat-select matSuffix formControlName="unit" >
  <ng-container *ngFor="let unit of unitArray" >
    <mat-option [value]="unit" >{{unit}}</mat-option>
  </ng-container>
</mat-select>
```

Then you can combine these two values on submit:

```
submit() {
  const value = `${this.form.value.width}${this.form.value.unit}`
  // use this value for whatever you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I try using 3 different controls *widthNum*, *unit* and *totalWidth*. In your.component.ts:

```
  exampleForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    widthNum: [''],
    unit: [''],
    widthWhitUnit: [''],
  });

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.exampleForm.get('widthNum').valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
      this.exampleForm
        .get('widthWhitUnit')
        .setValue(
          this.exampleForm.get('widthNum').value +
            ' ' +
            this.exampleForm.get('unit').value
        );
    });

    this.exampleForm.get('unit').valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
      this.exampleForm
        .get('widthWhitUnit')
        .setValue(
          this.exampleForm.get('widthNum').value +
            ' ' +
            this.exampleForm.get('unit').value
        );
    });
  }
}
```

And an example for your.component.html:

```
<div [formGroup]="exampleForm">
  <input formControlName="widthNum" placeholder="width" />
  <input formControlName="unit" placeholder="unit" />
</div>

<div>
  <p>{{ this.exampleForm.get('widthWhitUnit')?.value }}</p>
</div>
```

I provide you some code on stackblitz at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1gdwp3

Comment: Getting data from api and the formField are dynamically changed so i m using *ngFor every data and bind , So I need other solution

Comment: I don't understand, could you please explain your case?

Comment: Input fields are received through api. so, there's will be no.of  input fields for each fields we can't define formcontrol separately

Comment: You mean your *unitArray* are received from an api?